# Injecting factory into service fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I've setup an angular seed project with some services and a factory. `companyService` depends on a factory called company. Injecting company into `companyService` fails with this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=ResourceProvider%20%3C-%20Resource%20%3C-%20company%20%3C-%20companyService). I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
var module = angular.module('project.services', []);

module.factory('company', ['$rootScope', 'Resource', function($rootScope, $resource){
    return $resource($rootScope.api + 'companies/:id');
}]);

module.service('companyService',['$rootScope', '$http', 'company', function($rootScope, $http, company){
    var companies;

    //var $injector = angular.injector();
    //var company = $injector.get('company');

    // some more functions ....

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)** is a separate module, so you should include the `angular-resource[.min].js` script and declare `ngResource` as a dependency of your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', [..., 'ngResource']);
```